TV doesn't improve [creatvity]
creatvity appears to have been created as a misspelling of creativity. But what surprised me was that the former has a tag wiki and the latter doesn't. I don't see a benefit in keeping the misspelling around as a synonym. I've retagged a few through suggested edits; can a 2K finish the rest?

I wonder whether this soft delete will occur. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it
